# operational error in django database connection

Tags: python, django

I have setup the MySQL database in django. but I am getting the operational error such as unknown database.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    #'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dbname'),
    'USER':'root',
    'PASSWORD':'********',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'3306',
}
```

}

But it throws following error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database
>   'c:\users\brahmareddy\desktop\djangotable\checkingapp\djangodb'")

Comment: the `'ENGINE'` is `'django.db.backends.mysql'` but you want to connect to `'c:\users\brahmareddy\desktop\djangotable\checkingapp\dbname'` -- I think it is sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

your setting for mysql database should look like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

`Name` should not contain path, it is just the name of already running MySQL instance

`Host` is the IP Address of the MySQL server

Comment: i used this these parameters. but again its throws the same error.

Comment: can you paste the error here? also do have MSSql instance running somewhere with whom you want to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker, maybe you should check the docker volume.

```sh
docker volume --help
docker volume ls
docker volume  rm xx yy
```

Remove cache, restart.